# How to download NuGet package having native dll without referencing in project instead copying to output directory

Tags: .net, nuget-package, nuspec

I have a .NET project using native .dll using `[DllImport]` attributes. Our project guidelines forbid us from keeping any DLL as part of source code. I created NuGet package of same using nuspec file. Now problem is how to consume the package without referencing it to project. I would like to copy the DLL to output directory instead of referencing in the project.

I have tried adding in package config file and tried restoring packages using prebuild command and copying further which didn't work out.

Could anyone have any suggestion how to package native DLL and consume it in a project with referencing it somehow?

Comment: Please expand on "didn't work out". What was the issue or error? Are you really sure that if you're not allowed to take a reference to 3rd party DLLs you ARE allowed to use them just by dumping them into the bin folder?!

Comment: editing package.config file manually in order to restore the packages from nugget tries to install it in respective project which is where exception is thrown for not valid assembly as it's native library and can't be referenced directly. pre build event successfully downloads the packages but build fails while adding into the project.

Answer (score 1):

Not super sure what your are asking for, ie you want the dll to be in the build directory but not reference it in you project.

I guess you can do this with targets.

IE:
Nuget Nuspec file: (there are more required fields, but just listing the relevant fields)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>NugetName.Core</id>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\YourDll.dll" exclude="lib\net452\YourDll.dll" />
    <file src="YourDll.dll" target="build\YourDll.dll" />
    <file src="NugetName.Core.targets" target="build\" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The make a NugetName.Core.targets file

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)YourDll.dll">
      <Link>YourDll.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately this also throws error while installing the nugget package having targets file bundled together. "Failed to add reference to "my.dll" please make sure the file is accessible, and that its a valid assembly or COM component."

Comment: Sry to hear it, had not personally tried this with dll files myself (mostly use it with config files). I guess nuspec tries to add any dll file as a reference.  My only tip is to rename the extension (ie My._dll), but then you probably can load the dll?

Comment: Also you can try the updated code (exclude in nuspec) May have to edit to match your .net version.